# Print out the BER vs SNR function graph in python

Tags: python, snr

First of all if this isnt the place to post these types of exercise please point out where do i post it and thank you in advance

We are asked in this exercise to print out the SNR vs BER graphs for every given mod, these mods being `BPSK`,`QPSK`,`8QAM`,`16QAM`

We are asked to Define the classes and the methods and i belive ive done every thing correctly

This is that part of the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcol
from scipy.special import erfc
import math

color_dict = mcol.TABLEAU_COLORS


def lin2db(x):
    return 10*np.log10(x)


def db2lin(x):
    return 10**(x/10)

class ADC():
    fs_step = 2.75625e3
    def __init__(self,n_bit):
        self.n_bit=n_bit

    @property
    def snr(self):
        n_bit=self.n_bit
        M=2**n_bit
        snr_lin=M**2
        return snr_lin

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin=self.snr
        snr_db=lin2db(snr_lin)
        return snr_db

    @property
    def m(self):
        M=2**self.n_bit
        return M


class Digital_signal_information(object):
    def __init__(self, signal_power :float, noise_power :float, n_bit_mod:int):
        self.__signal_power=signal_power
        self.__noise_power=noise_power
        self.__n_bit_mod=n_bit_mod

    @property
    def nbit_mod(self):
        return self.__n_bit_mod

    @nbit_mod.setter
    def set_nbit_mod(self,value):
        self.__n_bit_mod=value

    @property
    def signal_power(self):
        return self.__signal_power

    @property
    def noise_power(self):
        return self.__noise_power

    @noise_power.setter
    def set_noise_power(self,val):
        self.__noise_power=val;


class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, loss_coefficient: float, length: float):
        self._loss_coefficient = loss_coefficient/1000
        self._length = length/1000

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @property
    def loss_coefficient(self):
        return self._loss_coefficient;

    @property
    def Loss(self):
        loss=self.loss_coefficient * self.length
        return loss

    def Noise_Generation(self,sn):
        noise_generation=1e-9 * sn * self.length
        return noise_generation

    def  snr_digital(self,sn):
        digital_snr=lin2db(sn)-lin2db(self.Noise_Generation(sn))-self.Loss
        return  digital_snr



class PCM:
    def __init__(self, digital_signal_info: Digital_signal_information, adc: ADC, line: Line):
        self._digital_signal_info = digital_signal_info
        self._adc = adc
        self._line = line

    @property
    def digital_signal_info(self):
        return self._digital_signal_info

    @property
    def adc(self):
        return self._adc

    @property
    def line(self):
        return self._line

    def snr_db(self):
        sn = self.digital_signal_info.signal_power
        snr_digital_db = self.line.snr_digital(sn)
        return snr_digital_db


    @property
    def snr_lin(self):
        snr_db=self.snr_db()
        snr_lin=db2lin(snr_db);
        return snr_lin

    @property
    def ber_evaluation(self):
        i=self.digital_signal_info.nbit_mod

        if ( i == 1 ):
                ber=0.5*erfc(math.sqrt(self.snr_lin))
        if ( i == 2 ):
                ber=0.5*erfc(math.sqrt(self.snr_lin*0.5))
        if ( i == 3 ):
                ber = 2/3 * erfc(math.sqrt(self.snr_lin * 3/14))
        if ( i == 4 ):
                ber = 3/8 * erfc(math.sqrt(self.snr_lin * 1/10))
        return ber

    @property
    def Snr_th(self):
        n_bit = self.adc.n_bit
        M=2**n_bit
        snr_q_lin=M**2
        snr_th_lin=0.5*snr_q_lin
        return snr_th_lin

    @property
    def Snr_th_db(self):
        n_bit = self.adc.n_bit
        snr_q_db=6*n_bit
        snr_th_db=snr_q_db-3
        return snr_th_db

    @property
    def critical_pe(self):
        n_bit = self.digital_signal_info.nbit_mod
        M = 2 ** n_bit
        P_eth=1/(4*(M**2-1))
        return P_eth
```

If you need explanations as to what these are:

In class ADC basically we find SNR_Q in linear and Db

In Class Digital_signal_information we simply define

In Class Line we basically we have to find the Snr_Digital which is in db

In Class PCM we combine all these classes

In Class PCM: the first SNR we simply receive it from Digital_signal_information. Then we transform it back to linear and we use this SNR to find each of the BERs depending on the value of n_bit_mod which can be [1,2,3,4]

Snr_th is Snr threshold and SNR_th_db is Snr threshold in db(wow i know)
And P_eth is basically a vertial line in the graph i want to print

Thing is how do i use these values to plot the log_10(BER) vs SNR curves?

```
signal_power=0.001
length=np.linspace(start=10000,stop=120000)
loss_coeficient=1
n_bit_mod=[1,2,3,4]
n_bit_adc=6
```